# Total Wages Calculations

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regexextract

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13HdNN_qa9rhLFyMe0N9I9EusmBudi_dcdBkc6UeLHMM/edit#gid=878850570

I am trying to total Normal Pay but the formula does not Multiply Regular Hours by Normal Rate hence I get an `R6.33` sum instead of `R152.00`

1. I would appreciate assistance with a formula to calculate Currency/Price from Duration or Time.
2. Also how to auto sum other cells? example - this formula `=SUM(H2:H*1.5)` to be applied every time a new input is made on the column?

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Changed to Public

Comment: how did you calculate 158.84?

Comment: The 158.84 under Total Wages was calculated by an AppSheet App Formula and not Sheet Formula

Comment: yeah, but is 158.84=8:21h * 19? in that case it should be E2*H2 not F2*H2, right?

Comment: My apologies, I am supposed to be getting "152", which should be reached by - . I want to calculate Regular Hours (on column F) multiply by Hourly Rate (column H)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 (REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(F2:F), "\d+")+
 (REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(F2:F), ":(\d+)"))/60+IFERROR
 (REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(F2:F), "\d+:\d+:(\d+)")/3600))*H2:H, ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), H2:H*1.5, ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 (REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(G2:G), "\d+")+IFERROR(
 (REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(G2:G), ":(\d+)"))/60)+IFERROR
 (REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(G2:G), "\d+:\d+:(\d+)")/3600))*I2:I, ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), J2:J+K2:K, ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi, I am using the google sheet on an Appsheet Timesheet App. I am trying to avoid having formulars that are not aligned, can you please assist me with a formula that would give a Total Hours = 17:00:00 if employee clocked in at 12:55pm today and ended 6:12am following day? I currently given a -6 | https://discourse-cdn-sjc1.com/business5/uploads/appsheet/original/2X/c/c971018af5322df3e49c749a317f3166bda4fdf3.png

Comment: I am not familiar with Appsheet Timesheet App